# Override jQuery custom event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got the following piece of code that will 'spread' an event to all my js modules. This is intended to be triggered when trying to move away from the current page. The issue is that I don't this to be triggered when the form is submitted (submit/cancel/save). Is there a way to check that?

main.js:

...

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
            var e = $.Event('webapp:page:closing');

            $(window).trigger(e);

            if (e.isDefaultPrevented()){
                return e.message || 'You have unsaved stuff!';
            }
        });
}
```

...

Comment: I like that little wrapper. I may have to use something like that. Right now I use a queue system, which has the advantage that handlers don't have to check whether the event has already been prevented by something else. (With the above, if you have multiple handlers preventing the default and setting `message`, the last one wins; with mine, the first one does [and the others aren't called]. Not sure how much that matters, though.)

Comment: I like your approach. Any general indication on how the queue should work? Thanks

Comment: Just a list of handlers (I shouldn't really have called it a queue) that get called in order by the real `beforeunload` handler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before submit/save/cancel, you can call below code which will remove the handler from all listeners

```
$(window).off('webapp:page:closing');
```

Comment: My mistake, I had commented out a line that was causing this not to work. It worked now, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

On form submit unbind the event:

```
$("#frm").submit(function(e) {
    $(window).off('beforeunload');
});
```

From MDN: The .off() method removes event handlers that were attached with .on()

Comment: Tried it but didn't work. In fact, it's not hitting the submit event

Comment: My mistake, I had commented out a line that was causing this not to work. It worked now, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The only way that comes to mind is: In the page with the form, when it handles the `webapp:page:closing` event, it should *not* prevent the default if it has submitted a form (which it can track via a variable in the page).

Comment: I tried this approach but didn't work. I created a global variable called form_submitted = false; and within $(window).on('beforeunload') ... I'm checking if form_submitted is false before triggering the custom event. But this is being hit first before reaching the submit event so my bool var is always false

Comment: My mistake, I had commented out a line that was causing this not to work. It worked now, thanks!